# pandas dataframe keep original precison values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change my value column into float:

```html
date,value,id
2021-02-02 06:00:00,"45896,552000000",12365
2021-02-06 02:15:00,"36985,552000000",12365
2021-02-07 15:30:00,"25693,552000000",12365
2021-03-03 18:45:00,"12593,5520000000",12365
2021-06-05 02:00:00,"0,0000000000000",12365
2021-06-05 02:15:00,"0,0000000000000",12365
```

I am trying:

```html
df["value1"] = [float(str(i).replace(",", ".")) for i in df['value']]


df['value1'] = df['value1''].astype(float)
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.9f}'.format
df['value1']
```

it is okay for values that have 9 precise values but some values have 11 or 12 values how can I deal with them
I also tried:

```html
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', np.format_float_positional):
    print(df.to_string())
```

but it is showing only 3 decimal values. how can I keep original float values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting a higher display precision, say `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.12f}'.format` ?

Comment: @yes then it totaly changed the values of decimal... instead of 0000000 it shows 966999999997

Comment: That, unfortunately, is how `float` works. You can take a look at the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)